# Cache DOM in Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the router (was using the built in one, now using ui-route but solutions for either are fine) in Angular.JS to switch between control/template pairs. When switching back and forth between a couple of these pages it takes up to a second to setup the DOM each time which looks terrible. Is there anyway of having angular keep around the DOM tree instead of recreating it each time. I guess I'd like to just hide/sow the bits for each page rather than remove/re-create them each time.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: You could hide/show areas with [ng-show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngShow). also you may want to look into [$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache) which will allow you to cache your views.

Comment: I guess I could us ng-show, but then wouldn't I have to throw away the hole router and url management that Angular provides? Not totally sure how to use $templateCache, can I set things up so that all templates are cached?

Comment: You could use two ng-app to manage two behaviors i guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to write your own ng-view directive to create such functionality.

The basic idea behind it is:

Before the route changes, instead of destroying the current view element, and scope, you just put it in an invisible cache DIV, and deregister scope listeners. Give the element a data attribute with the `$$route.templateUrl` to be able to get it back.
Then you fetch the next view from the server.

Before the route changes you check for cache item existance, and if it is in your cache div get the element from the cache, re-register listeners and put the current view the cache.

The tricky part is not to mess the `$scope`s up. So you might need a constructor and destructor in your `$scope` for the event, and maybe for the $watchers as well. I'm not sure.

But to be honest, if you using the template cache and still takes 1 second or so to render, then you might have some inefficient `$watch` expression, or a huge `ng-repeat`. You should consider some refact.

Comment: Is it really helps someone on real problem? If someone provide example(s) how it works with code will be great.

Answer (score 2):

I've been researching this myself.  I am working on rather old hardware in an unaccelerated browser.  Initial render is a problem.  My early work-around was to cache *pre-compiled* templates, as you are attempting.  I found that this provided only a minimal speed improvement.

The real bottleneck was coming from my ng-repeat directives, the number of reflows that resulted and the number of DOM nodes/watchers I was building in each iteration.

Some sources have suggested creating a custom directive which manually assembles the dom and appends it in one go.  The result is very minimal reflow and no watchers.  The downside is very large. No more angular fun and a lot of unnecessary work. More importantly, none of this provided a large enough speed improvement to justify the work.

I ultimately found that the best speed improvement came from forcing hardware acceleration for each ng-repeat iteration.  As suggested above, the ng-animate directive in newer versions angular make this relatively trivial.

You will see immediate page render, with minor reflow hiccups.  ng-cloak does not help here.  Due to the animation request, the page is not suposed to be cloaked while the repeat renders. These can, however, be rendered reasonably well with a bit of clever fun. I'm actually hiding the ng-repeat until the $location changes, showing a progress indicator in the meantime, and then toggling my ng-show.  This works really nicely.

Having said all of that, precompiling your templates should be done as follows.

1) When your app starts, create a new cache for yourself. See http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/api/ng.$cacheFactory

2) Populate this cache with *compiled* templates.  Inject $compile and call it on each template.  Compile returns a function which you will later call against your scope. Key this function in your cache as you see fit.

3) Create a custom directive which accepts a cache key as an attribute.  Inside this directive, query your compile cache for the correct compile function.  Call the function against your current scope, and append the resulting DOM to the element passed into the directive.

4) Sorta win :).

Comment: can u guide me how to do part 3 ? query ur compile cache for the correct compile function ?

Comment: Is there some live example for this method?

There are tons of things hidden here:

Answer (score 0):

If you move up to Angular 1.1.5, you can use the ng-animate attribute on you ng-view tag.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it does some DOM caching to make the transitions work better. You could try adding adding ng-animate attribute to your tag. That might take care of it for you.